# ImportError: cannot import name model_fn: Tensorflow

Tags: python, ios, tensorflow

I have successfully generated retrained_graph.pb and retrained_labels.txt model.

But not able to convert the Model into TFLite format.

Using following versions

tensorflow                             1.12.0
tensorflow-gpu                         1.1.0

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** You may use `tflite_convert` a **command line tool** to achieve this.
Starting from TensorFlow 1.9, the command-line tool `tflite_convert` is installed as part of the Python package.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples#command-line_tools_
You can simply try following from command line;

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=/tmp/foo.tflite \
  --graph_def_file=/tmp/frozen_graph.pb \
  --input_arrays=input \
  --output_arrays=output
```

The values for --input_arrays and --output_arrays are the inputs and outputs in your TensorFlow graph.

---

**(2)** You may also try to use **Python API** to convert GraphDef into TFLite format
See exporting a graphdef from a file https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_graphdef_from_file_
You can try this template;

```py
import tensorflow as tf

graph_def_file = "/path/to/Downloads/your_model/frozen_graph.pb"
input_arrays = ["input"]
output_arrays = ["output"]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Note it only supports GraphDefs frozen using [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py).

Hope this helps.